# Regarding Thread safety and JPA EntityManager

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

Suppose we have two entities dependant to each other and DAOs for each of them

```
Entity1 -> * Entity2
Entity2
```

now suppose we have two threads that are pulling some data from database, Thread1 asks Entity1Dao to get some object with dependant fields initialized, meanwhile Thread2 tries to get same Entity2 objects (already retrieved) with Entity2Dao.

Entity1Dao creates EntityManager (em1) and retrieves data, and Entity2Dao will create different EntityManager (em2) to get queries objects from database.

QUESTION: Does em2 stay locked until em1 get closed? if not should we get exception on "other entitymanager containing requested object"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Every EntityManager will return different instances of the entities.

The concurrent transactions will then, potentially, write to the same rows, and the last one will win, unless you implement optimistic concurrency (by adding an `@Version` field to your entities).

Comment: Thanks for answers, could you please answer to this too. Suppose I've got some Object (attached) form entity manager and later closed em, is that object still attached?

Comment: No. If you close the `em`, all the objects that were managed by the `em` become unmanaged.

Comment: I'm trying to implement data access layer for my aplication, and only way I discovered to make it thread safe is to use entityManager per transaction, so as you said any object returned from dao will become unmanaged. Is there some better approach to do this?

Comment: At first I've tried to keep my entity Managers alive and reuse them, but very soon I've got exceptions like 'entity is already loaded by another entity manager', not sure what to do? any literature you can recomment on this?

Comment: Transactions should not be started and committed by the data access layer. Use Java EE or Spring to handle transactions declaratively for you, at the service layer, or reinvent them (but I would avoid that).

Comment: Thanks seems I have wrong understanding of how JPA works and transactions managed...

Answer (score 3):

The entity managers are totally independent in this case. There are mechanisms of [optimistic locking](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html) and [pessimistic locking](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html) offered by JPA that you could use to coordinate what should happen during two transaction dealing with the same data.

See the [JPA 2.1 Specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338), section 3.4 about Locking and Concurrency.